# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sql_regcase()

Tags: php

I know that using PHP functions to avoid anti-sql injections is a bad idea, but I'm trying solve this function issue for custom purposes

```
function anti_injection($sql){
   $sql = preg_replace(sql_regcase("/(from|select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|#|\*|--|\\\\)/"), "" ,$sql);
   $sql = trim($sql);
   $sql = strip_tags($sql);
   $sql = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $sql : addslashes($sql);
   return $sql;
}
```

I'm getting this error: `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sql_regcase()`

How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: This code is *useless* and will not protect you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sql_regcase was deprecated in PHP 5.3.0, and removed in PHP 7.0.0.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sql-regcase.php

Answer (score 1):

This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.

Alternatives to this function include:

preg_match()
preg_quote()
source `https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sql-regcase.php`